# Nuxt2 window.__nuxt__ routePath does not match the current path

Tags: vue.js, nginx, nuxt.js

I found a problem, I use nuxt generate project, but I want to use nginx for a layer of proxy. I used proxy_pass.

As a result, I found a.com/articles/xxx, and the proxy to the nuxt project is c.com/test/xx.

It is a static page, but the interface is called again. If I change it to a.com/test/xx, it will not be called.

I found out that it is caused by the inconsistency of the routePath of window.**nuxt**. How to solve this problem?